# Would this be right to respond to all the reviewers queries simultaneously in single files along with their queries?

Tags: peer-review

I have prepared all answers to all the queries raised by reviewers in major revision. Would it be ok if I respond to both reviewers in single pdf file in following format:

> **Reviewer #1:**
>
> Query 1: Reviewer's first query.
>
> Author response: This is my explanation.
>
> Query 2: Reviewer's second query.
>
> Author response: This is my explanation.

and so on....

> **Reviewer #2:**
>
> Query 1: Reviewer's first query.
>
> Author response: This is my explanation.
>
> Query 2: Reviewer's second query.
>
> Author response: This is my explanation.

In this way both reviewers can see queries of each other. Is this right way of response to reviewers ?

Comment: You are thinking about it too much. If you weren't told about any preferred formats, I'd go with separate responses, as not to confuse the reviewers.

Answer (score 9):

As a reviewer I have no problem with all the responses in one document. In practice I will quickly scroll down to my comments, but I may glance at responses on comments I find interesting.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is usually ok tobrespond to all reviewers in one file or message. After all, answers to one reviewer might well be interesting for the others, as well.

Coming from a field where answers to reviewers are generally subject to a tight length limit, I would even go a step further and mix/aggregate the answers to different reviewers. Different reviewers often ask the same or related questions, or make suggestions that complement or even contradict one another. As you have to produce one revised version of the paper that needs to suit all reviewers, the comments by different reviewers also need to be considered as a whole rather than per reviewer.

Answer (score 4):

As a referee I would expect the author's reply to mention all of the ways that the paper has changed since I last saw it (whether those changes were prompted by my comments, another reviewer or editors comments, or just the authors realizing that something should change).  After all, these changes might introduce new errors or problems!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which journal you were talking about, but mostly journals with online submission facility give accessing the reviewers' comments to each reviewer. Though there are two different options:-1) comments to editor and 2) comments to authors, but the 2nd one i.e comments to authors can be viewed by all the reviewers. Moreover, in general, editor sends all the reviewers' comment in one file along with his own comments and decisions to authors as well as to the reviewers. So it is always good to make it in one file.